# How to increase time of Balloon pop-up notification on windows

Tags: python, windows, winapi, notifications, pywin32

I am using balloon pop-up notification to show user notification messages.
It lasts for only 5 secs as by default windows notification setting comes up with 5 sec time.

My code is:

```
from win32api import *
from win32con import NULL
from win32gui import *
import win32com.client as com
import win32con
import win32file
import time


class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg,notlivelong):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        iconPathName= "D:\cc.ico"

        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd) 
        print iconPathName
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
            hicon = LoadImage(hinst,iconPathName, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16,icon_flags)
        except:
            hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
#             logging.debug("Image adding fail")
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "TITLE")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)

        global sleep
        time.sleep(2)
        if notlivelong:
            DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
            UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, None)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        # Terminate the app.

def balloon_tip(title, msg,notlivelong):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg,notlivelong)


balloon_tip("title1", "msg1",False) #iF True, then last for 2 sec.
```

How to make this balloon pop-up to stay for longer duration. Also consider the case, pop-up should stay long in presence of mouse-movement also. Also, after invoking pop-up, process should terminate but pop-up should stay.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of time to display a notification balloon is a user-setting, and not an application setting.  In fact, as of Windows Vista the timeout value of the [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure is actively ignored.  The reason for this is that notification balloons are there [to be ignored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx#rightcontrol).  If you think that your information is too important to be ignored by the user, then you're using the wrong kind of interface to start with.

Having said that, it *is* possible to programatically change the settings by using the `SystemParametersInfo` API, but I encourage you to *not do that*, as it will affect the setting at a system-wide level, and that's not your call to make.